# Alternative Window Manager

Tags: debian, software-rec, window-manager

Is there a window manager, easy to install on Debian, that uses very little resources?

I only need bash and Firefox/Chrome, java and flash.
And maybe something like notepad++ for Linux. Though I'm rather quick with Vi.

My Samsung NC10 is running far too slow with Ubuntu/Gnome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a list of your options here on the debian.org website:

- https://wiki.debian.org/DesktopEnvironment

*excerpt from that page*

> Desktop Environments
>
> - The [GNOME](https://wiki.debian.org/Gnome) project provides two things: The GNOME desktop environment, an intuitive and attractive desktop for users, and the GNOME development platform, an extensive framework for building applications that integrate into the rest of the desktop.
> - [KDE](https://wiki.debian.org/KDE) is a powerful open source graphical desktop environment for Unix workstations. It combines ease of use, contemporary functionality, and outstanding graphical design with the technological superiority of the Unix operating system.
> - [Xfce](https://wiki.debian.org/Xfce) is a lightweight desktop environment for various *NIX systems. Designed for productivity, it loads and executes applications fast, while conserving system resources.
> - [LXDE](https://wiki.debian.org/LXDE) is designed to work well with computers on the low end of the performance spectrum such as older resource-constrained machines, new generation netbooks, and other small computers.
>
> Window Managers
>
> - [Openbox](https://wiki.debian.org/Openbox) is a lightweight and highly configurable window manager with extensive standards support. Its features are well-documented at the official website.
> - [FluxBox](https://wiki.debian.org/FluxBox) is a windowmanager for X that was based on the Blackbox 0.61.1 code. It is very light on resources and easy to handle but yet full of features to make an easy, and extremely fast, desktop experience..
> - [Compiz](https://wiki.debian.org/Compiz) is compositing window managers for the X Window System that uses 3D graphics hardware to create fast compositing desktop effects for window management.
> - [Wmii](https://wiki.debian.org/Wmii) is a dynamic window manager for X11. It supports classic and tiling window management with extended keyboard, mouse, and filesystem based remote control. It replaces the workspace paradigm with a new tagging approach.
> - [Awesome](https://wiki.debian.org/Awesome) is a dynamic window manager for X11. It supports tiling window management with extended keyboard, mouse, and it is scriptable in Lua. It includes many add-ons which can make it very powerful. It replaces the workspace paradigm with a new tiling approach of non-overlaping windows.

Comment: Tch -- fvwm is missing!!!  So a somewhat partial list.

Comment: @goldilocks - hah doesn't anyone use that anymore? I haven't heard it mentioned for like 10+ years until you said it.

Comment: Pretty sure the current lead maintainer is actually younger than it, lol.  I think he was handed a torch.  There is still a sizable hard core fan base and it really puts other stuff to shame, configurability wise (eg, openbox).  Once you have the `~/.fvwmrc` you want, it is hard to walk away ;)

Comment: @goldilocks - yes I remember wasting entirely too much time screwing with that file. Wish I could have that time back 8-). Why the name Goldilocks BTW?

Comment: All about the porridge!

Comment: @goldilocks - well now you'll have to elaborate! I thought of Gentoo, but that's portage.

Comment: (..just got back from vacation) *"Goldilocks and the Three Bears"* is an English or European fairy tale (I think at least everyone who grew up in the English speaking world will know it).  Goldilocks is a little girl who sneaks into the cabin of three bears (Mamma, Pappa, and Baby) while they are out and tastes their porridge: one is too hot, one too cold, and one *just right*.  Then she eats all of (Baby bear's) "just right" porridge. So: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldilocks_principle emphasizes this "perfect" balance; to me it is also about subjectivity and her personality.

Comment: @goldilocks - I'm aware of the story and the reference to the goldilocks zone too, not the last bit so much, but it makes sense. Much deeper meaning to your alias. Mine's so boring, I just picked my initials 8-).

Answer (score 2):

The Arch Wiki has a typically detailed page listing almost all of the [window managers that run on X](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Window_managers#List_of_window_managers), including a brief description and links to their home pages.

Additionally, there is another page that has a helpful [comparison of tiling window managers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Comparison_of_Tiling_Window_Managers), which may help you narrow down your choice of a lightweight, configurable window manager.

Answer (score 2):

How about to try xfce, it does approx what gnome2 but better and with with less resources. (apt-get install xfce4).

If that is to heavy try [enlightenment](http://www.enlightenment.org/), it is light on resource but still nice to look at.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a window manager, easy to install on Debian, that uses very little resources?

Window managers in general do not use that much in the way of resources.  Although the NC10 has relatively poor specs, any *stand alone* window manager should be fine, so do not choose on that basis.

However, it is **very important** you understand the difference between a window manager and a *desktop environment*.  Desktop environments (such as GNOME) pretty much by definition use more resources than a window manager because they  require a window manager -- whereas many window managers do not require a desktop environment (hence, they are "stand alone").  DE's aspire to be more than WM's and so are heavier resource wise, often very significantly.  However, a good stand alone window manager can still provide you with a complete, highly configurable desktop, including task bars, menus, etc.

> I only need bash and Firefox/Chrome, java and flash. And maybe something like...

Window managers do not impose limits upon what additional software you want to use.  They also generally do not provide any, whereas desktop environments include an application suite consisting of at least a file browser.  In other words, your choice of window managers has nothing to do with your choice of web browser, web browser plugin, java interpreter, editor, etc. etc.  All web browsers available for linux will work on any window manager, and the same goes for java interpreters and serious editors.

An exception to this is applications that are explicitly part of a desktop environment, which may or may not work without that DE.  So, for example, if you like Nautilus, it probably will work outside GNOME, although perhaps with reduced functionality.  This is something to consider because you do need a file browser.  Most of the decent GUI terminals today are also associated with a DE, but will work without it.  For example, I really like the XFCE Terminal, but I don't use XFCE.  It can be used with a stand-alone WM, and with other DE's (e.g., I use it with KDE instead of the KDE terminal, and with **fvwm**, a great old school stand-alone WM).